# Stream mjpeg (or any other format/method) from my Pi 3 camera to another server in AWS

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, streaming-video, server, streaming

I am looking to "tunnel", "forward", "bridge" an mjpeg stream from mi Raspberry Pi 3 to a server I have on AWS (Linux). I have currently tried the UV4L packages to stream video in my LAN and I have succeeded.

The problem I have is that my router is behind a private IP 10.100.xx.x and I have no control over the Modem my router is connected to since I live in an apartment complex (and they will obviously refuse to give me access to it) and by what I read [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=75243) I think there is no way I can connect my pi to the outside world (as explained by klricks @ Thu Apr 24, 2014 12:38 pm in that thread).

Therefore, I have decided that my way to circumvent this problem is to somehow stream (not necessarily using UV4L or MJPEG, any other protocol/package/way is fine) my pi camera's video to my server hosted on AWS. Then my server will act as a mediator/proxy, and will serve the stream to other clients. I don't really need anything fancy, I am looking for something that works (but I am open to fancier solutions).

I have used nginx for some stuff, so I was wondering if I could stream it over that... Or if there are any open source video streaming solutions that can be installed in a server...

Do any of you have any suggestions?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have the solution under your nose and don't see it :) ? UV4L also supports VP8/H264 audio/video streaming through Janus Gateway or Jitsi Meet over internet/WAN which should not require to setup your firewall/NAT in any particular way. MJPEG is just obsolete for this kind of things. UV4L has been already used with AWS, I suggest that you ask the Janus server google group mailing list for more informations.